# Using Powershell, how to return a list of files based on the existence of duplicate files with a different naming convention?

Tags: powershell, get-childitem

There are multiple .webp files in a project folder. Some .webps are the original picture and some function as thumbnail (their size is different). The used naming convention is: original files are just called NAME.webp and tumbnails are NAME-thumb.webp.

I am trying to return all `.webp` files based on if the corresponding thumb-webp exists. So if picture SAMPLE.webp has a SAMPLE-thumb.webp, don't add this file to the list. But if SAMPLE.webp doesn't have a corresponding SAMPLE-thumb.webp, then do at it to the list.

This is what i've tried so far:

```
$example = Get-ChildItem -File $dir\*.webp |
        Group-Object { $_.BaseName } |
          Where-Object { $_.Name -NotContains "-thumb" } |
            ForEach-Object Group
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get this without the grouping with a `Where-Object` and testing paths.

```
Get-ChildItem -File $dir\*.webp |
    Where-Object {$_.Name -notmatch "-thumb" -and -not(Test-Path ($_.FullName -replace ".webp","-thumb.webp"))}
```

This should get you a list of all the files that do not have a corresponding thumbnail file.

Answer (score 1):

You can do the following:

```
(Get-ChildItem $dir\*.webp -File |
    Group-Object {$_.BaseName -replace '-thumb$'} |
        Where Count -eq 1).Group
```

You must have a commonality with grouping. Replacing the ending `-thumb` in the `BaseName` property creates that. If there is no `filename` and `filename-thumb` the resulting `GroupInfo` will have a count value of `1`.

Using the syntax `().Group` returns all file objects. If you want to process code against each file, you may use `Foreach-Object` instead:

```
Get-ChildItem $dir\*.webp -File |
    Group-Object {$_.BaseName -replace '-thumb$'} |
        Where Count -eq 1 | Foreach-Object {
            $_.Group
        }
```